# Inject shared library into a process

Tags: c, linux

I just started to learn injection techniques in Linux and want to write a simple program to inject a shared library into a running process. (the library will simply print a string.) However, after a couple of hours research, I couldn't find any complete example. Well, I did figure out I probably need to use ptrace() to pause the process and inject the contents, but not sure how to load the library into the memory space of target process and relocation stuff in C code. Does anyone know any good resources or working examples for shared library injection? (Of course, I know there might be some existing libraries like hotpatch I can use to make injection much easier but that's not what I want)

And if anyone can write some pseudo code or give me an example, I will appreciate it. Thanks.

PS: I am not asking about LD_PRELOAD trick.

Comment: Do you know about "LD_PRELOAD" trick? Maybe it suffices your needs?

Comment: if you are able to execute arbitrary code through some sort of trampoline or overflow... then you can dlopen/dlload a library function... but your exploit depends on where you are... otherwise you could look at overlaying an image... but this is all very dependent on your env.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you can't just use dlopen() and dlsym().

Comment: My mistake. Never mind. dlopen() is working. I just wonder how to load it into process's mem space and reallocate library's functions so that they can be executed after resuming the process.

Answer (score 39):

The "LD_PRELOAD trick" André Puel mentioned in a comment to the original question, is no trick, really. It is the standard method of adding functionality -- or more commonly, *interposing* existing functionality -- in a dynamically-linked process. It is standard functionality provided by [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), the Linux dynamic linker.

The Linux dynamic linker is controlled by environment variables (and configuration files); `LD_PRELOAD` is simply an environment variable that provides a list of dynamic libraries that should be linked against each process. (You could also add the library to `/etc/ld.so.preload`, in which case it is automatically loaded for every binary, regardless of the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.)

Here's an example, *example.c*:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));

static void wrerr(const char *p)
{
    const char *q;
    int        saved_errno;

    if (!p)
        return;

    q = p;
    while (*q)
        q++;

    if (q == p)
        return;

    saved_errno = errno;

    while (p < q) {
        ssize_t n = write(STDERR_FILENO, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > 0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != (ssize_t)-1 || errno != EINTR)
            break;
    }

    errno = saved_errno;
}

static void init(void)
{
    wrerr("I am loaded and running.\n");
}
```

Compile it to `libexample.so` using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -fPIC -shared example.c -ldl -Wl,-soname,libexample.so -o libexample.so
```

If you then run any (dynamically linked) binary with the full path to `libexample.so` listed in `LD_PREALOD` environment variable, the binary will output *"I am loaded and running"* to standard output before its normal output. For example,

```
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libexample.so date
```

will output something like

```
I am loaded and running.
Mon Jun 23 21:30:00 UTC 2014
```

Note that the `init()` function in the example library is automatically executed, because it is marked [`__attribute__((constructor))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconstructor_007d-function-attribute-2868); that attribute means the function will be executed prior to `main()`.

My example library may seem funny to you -- no `printf()` et cetera, `wrerr()` messing with `errno` --, but there are very good reasons I wrote it like this.

First, `errno` is a thread-local variable. If you run some code, initially saving the original `errno` value, and restoring that value just before returning, the interrupted thread will not see any change in `errno`. (And because it is thread-local, nobody else will see any change either, unless you try something silly like `&errno`.) Code that is supposed to run without the rest of the process noticing random effects, better make sure it keeps `errno` unchanged in this manner!

The `wrerr()` function itself is a simple function that writes a string safely to standard error. It is async-signal-safe (meaning you can use it in signal handlers, unlike `printf()` et al.), and other than `errno` which is kept unchanged, it does not affect the state of the rest of the process in any way. Simply put, it is a safe way to output strings to standard error. It is also simple enough for everbody to understand.

Second, not all processes use standard C I/O. For example, programs compiled in Fortran do not. So, if you try to use standard C I/O, it might work, it might not, or it might even confuse the heck out of the target binary. Using the `wrerr()` function avoids all that: it will just write the string to standard error, without confusing the rest of the process, no matter what programming language it was written in -- well, as long as that language's runtime does not move or close the standard error file descriptor (`STDERR_FILENO == 2`).

---

To load that library dynamically in a running process, you'll need to first attach `ptrace` to it, then stop it before next entry to a syscall (`PTRACE_SYSEMU`), to make sure you're somewhere you can safely do the dlopen call.

Check `/proc/PID/maps` to verify you are within the process' own code, not in shared library code. You can do `PTRACE_SYSCALL` or `PTRACE_SYSEMU` to continue to next candidate stopping point. Also, remember to `wait()` for the child to actually stop after attaching to it, and that you attach to all threads.

While stopped, use `PTRACE_GETREGS` to get the register state, and `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` to copy enough code, so you can replace it with `PTRACE_POKETEXT` to a position-independent sequence that calls `dlopen("/path/to/libexample.so", RTLD_NOW)`, `RTLD_NOW` being an integer constant defined for your architecture in `/usr/include/.../dlfcn.h`, typically 2. Since the pathname is constant string, you can save it (temporarily) over the code; the function call takes a pointer to it, after all.

Have that position-independent sequence you used to rewrite some of the existing code end with a syscall, so that you can run the inserted using `PTRACE_SYSCALL` (in a loop, until it ends up at that inserted syscall) without having to single-step it. Then you use `PTRACE_POKETEXT` to revert the code to its original state, and finally `PTRACE_SETREGS` to revert the program state to what its initial state was.

---

Consider this trivial program, compiled as say `target`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while (EOF != (c = getc(stdin)))
        putc(c, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Let's say we're already running that (pid `$(ps -o pid= -C target)`), and we wish to inject code that prints *"Hello, world!"* to standard error.

On x86-64, kernel syscalls are done using the `syscall` instruction (`0F 05` in binary; it's a two-byte instruction). So, to execute any syscall you want on behalf of a target process, you need to replace two bytes. (On x86-64 PTRACE_POKETEXT actually transfers a 64-bit word, preferably aligned on a 64-bit boundary.)

Consider the following program, compiled to say `agent`:

```
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct user_regs_struct oldregs, regs;
    unsigned long  pid, addr, save[2];
    siginfo_t      info;
    char           dummy;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s PID ADDRESS\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[1], " %lu %c", &pid, &dummy) != 1 || pid < 1UL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid process ID.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], " %lx %c", &addr, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid address.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (addr & 7) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Address is not a multiple of 8.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Attach to the target process. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot attach to process %lu: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    /* Wait for attaching to complete. */
    waitid(P_PID, (pid_t)pid, &info, WSTOPPED);

    /* Get target process (main thread) register state. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, (pid_t)pid, NULL, &oldregs)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get register state from process %lu: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Save the 16 bytes at the specified address in the target process. */
    save[0] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, (pid_t)pid, (void *)(addr + 0UL), NULL);
    save[1] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, (pid_t)pid, (void *)(addr + 8UL), NULL);

    /* Replace the 16 bytes with 'syscall' (0F 05), followed by the message string. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, (pid_t)pid, (void *)(addr + 0UL), (void *)0x2c6f6c6c6548050fULL) ||
        ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, (pid_t)pid, (void *)(addr + 8UL), (void *)0x0a21646c726f7720ULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot modify process %lu code: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Modify process registers, to execute the just inserted code. */
    regs = oldregs;
    regs.rip = addr;
    regs.rax = SYS_write;
    regs.rdi = STDERR_FILENO;
    regs.rsi = addr + 2UL;
    regs.rdx = 14; /* 14 bytes of message, no '\0' at end needed. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, (pid_t)pid, NULL, &regs)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set register state from process %lu: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Do the syscall. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot execute injected code to process %lu: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Wait for the client to execute the syscall, and stop. */
    waitid(P_PID, (pid_t)pid, &info, WSTOPPED);

    /* Revert the 16 bytes we modified. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, (pid_t)pid, (void *)(addr + 0UL), (void *)save[0]) ||
        ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, (pid_t)pid, (void *)(addr + 8UL), (void *)save[1])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot revert process %lu code modifications: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Revert the registers, too, to the old state. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, (pid_t)pid, NULL, &oldregs)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot reset register state from process %lu: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Detach. */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, (pid_t)pid, NULL, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot detach from process %lu: %s.\n", pid, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It takes two parameters: the pid of the target process, and the address to use to replace with the injected executable code.

The two magic constants, `0x2c6f6c6c6548050fULL` and `0x0a21646c726f7720ULL`, are simply the native representation on x86-64 for the 16 bytes

```
0F 05 "Hello, world!\n"
```

with no string-terminating NUL byte. Note that the string is 14 characters long, and starts two bytes after the original address.

On my machine, running `cat /proc/$(ps -o pid= -C target)/maps` -- which shows the complete address mapping for the target -- shows that target's code is located at 0x400000 .. 0x401000. `objdump -d ./target` shows that there is no code after 0x4006ef or so. Therefore, addresses 0x400700 to 0x401000 are reserved for executable code, but do not contain any. The address 0x400700 -- on my machine; may very well differ on yours! -- is therefore a very good address for injecting code into target while it is running.

Running `./agent $(ps -o pid= -C target) 0x400700` injects the necessary syscall code and string to the target binary at 0x400700, executes the injected code, and replaces the injected code with original code. Essentially, it accomplishes the desired task: for target to output *"Hello, world!"* to standard error.

Note that Ubuntu and some other Linux distributions nowadays allow a process to ptrace only their child processes running as the same user. Since target is not a child of agent, you either need to have superuser privileges (run `sudo ./agent $(ps -o pid= -C target) 0x400700`), or modify target so that it explicitly allows the ptracing (for example, by adding [`prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, PR_SET_PTRACER_ANY);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) near the start of the program). See [man ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) and [man prctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) for details.

Like I explained already above, for longer or more complicated code, use ptrace to cause the target to first execute `mmap(NULL, page_aligned_length, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)`, which allocates executable memory for new code. So, on x86-64, you only need to locate one 64-bit word you can replace safely, and then you can PTRACE_POKETEXT the new code for the target to execute. While my example uses the write() syscall, it is a really small change to have it use mmap() or mmap2() syscall instead.

(On x86-64 in Linux, the syscall number is in rax, and parameters in rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, and r9, reading from left to right, respectively; and return value is also in rax.)

Parsing `/proc/PID/maps` is very useful -- see /proc/PID/maps under [man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). It provides all the pertinent information on the target process address space. To find out whether there are useful unused code areas, parse `objdump -wh /proc/$(ps -o pid= -C target)/exe` output; it examines the actual binary of the target process directly. (In fact, you could easily find how much unused code there is at the end of the code mapping, and use that automatically.)

Further questions?

Comment: Sorry, LD_PREALOD way is not what I want. I am asking a way to do injection stuff. In that case, I have to use ptrace(). Do you have any good example about how to load library into memory space properly and reallocate the functions? Thanks.

Comment: So far, I have attached a process using PTRACE_ATTACH and then use dlopen to load the library and store its returned reference, but I am not sure how to map to memory space of target process and how to use that register values got from PTRACE_GETREGS. Thanks.

Comment: @user1726119: You do realize you need to execute the dlopen in the ptraced process itself? Calling dlopen() in the process that is doing the ptrace call will have no effect in the ptraced process; the two do not share address spaces. You will have to modify some existing code in the target, to execute your injected dlopen call -- or at least enough for a `mmap(0,page,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0)` syscall to get a new executable page to put the dlopen calling code into. But you do need to overwrite existing code in all cases, AFAIK.

Comment: @user1726119: I added a tested, working example for x86-64, which injects a `write(STDERR, "Hello, world!\n", 14)` into a target process, temporarily rewriting 16 bytes at a specified target address (which must be in its own text section).

Comment: Very nice answer btw.