# linux dynamic link library injection

Tags: c++, linux, debian, code-injection

currently I'm working on some application plugin written in C++ - on windows I'm injecting dll into process, capturing interfaces and doing my work - but my question is - how can I do something similar on linux? I would prefer doing it without editing executable - code injection to running process.

Comment: Have you looked at dlopen & company?

Comment: @sfjac what do you mean by that? If I'm not wrong it's used to load dynamic library into current process, but I want to inject library A into process B which is running

Answer (score 1):

If you can control the startup of the process, simply use `LD_PRELOAD` to force-load a library alongside the executable, possibly shadowing symbols from other libraries (that are linked into the binary):

```
 LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libfoo.so myapplication
```

Following is a real-world use-case for adding a v4l2-support layer to v4l1-only applications, by intercepting `ioctl`:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so camorama
```

To inject symbols into already running processes, checkout out [this answer](/questions/27137527).

Comment: and if you want runtime attachement, use something liek explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137527/overload-symbols-of-running-process-ld-preload-attachement

Comment: @milianw, yes i just noticed that (answer!) as well and have already added that to my answer...

Comment: oh - sorry. didn't see it for some reason.

Comment: @milianw, that's because i added it (@ 21:25) while you were typing (@ 21:23) :-)