# Linux Injected Shared Object Self-Removal

Tags: c, linux, code-injection, shared-objects

So I have been working on Injecting Linux Shared Objects into running processes following information from [Inject shared library into a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355344/inject-shared-library-into-a-process) and https://github.com/gaffe23/linux-inject.  I've gotten it up and running fairly well.  My question pertains to removing the shared object afterwards.  I know I can use the same method as for injection, but what I need to know is if I can remove the shared object using code within it.

For example, I inject the .so and then remove the injector.  Now I need a way to remove the .so using functionality built into the .so itself.  I've thought about placing the injection code into the .so and then forking a process after a period of time just to test the idea.  Is this feasible or is there something else that would work better?

Answer (score 0):

It not trivial, but you can do the following when you decide to unload your shared object:

- mmap() a new mapping with EXECUTE permissions
- Write machine instructions on this mapping that dlclose(your-shared-object)
- write machine instructions that call munmap() while making sure the return address of this invocation points to a thread termination call (possibly pthread_exit()), resulting the executing thread to never return
- Create new thread and call the mmap() address